# Will a Potion of Glibness increase the money I get from selling things to vendors?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

It says "increases Speechcraft by xx for xx sec", but what does "Speechcraft" really mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Higher speechcraft will give you better prices.  However, your necklace with 10% better prices is much better than +15 speechcraft.  +15 speechcraft works out to be about 7.3% better prices.  That almost 3% difference can really add up in your coin purse over time.

Answer (score 4):

Speechraft is, among other things, the skill that affects prices you'll get from vendors. So yes, a Potion of Glibness will get you better prices.

It will also improve the success rate of your Persuade and Intimidate attempts.

Comment: As an extra note: The effect's linear. Fortify Speechcraft, as an enchantment, outright says "Prices are X% better".

Comment: @Kyte: That actually raises a seperate, and far more interesting question... Time to do some research.

Comment: I have two necklaces, however, one that grants +15 speechcraft, and another that gives 10% better price...Perhaps it only grants the % when you enchant yourself?

Comment: No, turns out there're two different spell effects. "X of haggling" will give better prices. "X of glibness" or similar go to speechcraft.

Comment: Please note a speech level of over 100 does nothing to buying and selling prices. An item, blessing and/or potion boosting the skill will improve your buying and selling prices, but only up to 100 speech. As your actual speech level rises and approaches 100, these will have less and less effect on your bartering until you actually hit 100 speech, and then they won't affect your prices anymore.